# Where can I recruit survivors easily?

Tags: survivalist

I'm on Day 10 now and still haven't recruited a single survivor. I get the feeling that I'm supposed to have recruited at least one person by now.

I read that you can recruit Sarah Slaughter after Duck Hunt, but she seems to have disappeared. I helped a bunch of other people but none of them seem interested in joining me, they're all too loyal to their current homes.

Where are you supposed to pick up your first recruits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they say something like "*I could never leave....*" or "*This is my home...*", then they can't be recruited without a strong event going on (camp gets taken out, etc). If they say "*you are cool and all, but...*" or something along the lines of "*you have some skills, but...*", then they can be persuaded. You just need to work them over a bit more. Trade with them, get work from them, fisticuffs with them, or give them the commodities that they like (smokes, wine, novels, etc).

Looters are probably one the easier recruits to find, but not the easiest. You can find their camps on the map, or through the quests that you do. The last man alive tends to give up. You have the option to recruit him/her to your community. But they won't always join (especially if they have a bold personality, preferring to die than join you). But more bodies really helps.

You know about Sarah Slaughter (a great recruit if I may add). You can also recruit Toby Reed. Toby is the guy living in a house on a hill between you and Fort Kohai. You can murder his wife, causing him to reluctantly join you (great farmer, definitely a good recruit). However, his wife is a beast with a shotgun so watch out. You can also recruit his wife by doing the quest for Toby. After he dies, she will blame you for his death (and depending how you answer, you may have a fight on your hands). Get someone kind and sympathetic to do the quest (Alice is a good one), and you can get good relationship points with Toby's wife. From then, you just work her over until she joins.